# What is exactly the object Entry?

Tags: java

I am actually working with a TreeMap on Java. I looked for how to iterate it, and I was doubting about rather using the `keySet()` method and iterate over it or use the `entrySet()` method and do so.

What I wanted to know is what exactly does an Entrt represent? Is it a copy of an 'object' in my tree map?

I just wanted to figure it out so I could choose rather using `keySet()` for iterating over the keys, or `entrySet()`.

Comment: Are you talking about the `Map.Entry` class? See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html

Comment: An `Entry` is an object representing a (key, value) pair in your map.  It is more efficient to iterate your map's entry set than to iterate its key set and use each key to retrieve the corresponding value.  If you don't care about the values then there is no advantage to using the entry set over the key set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) it is

> A map entry (key-value pair)

It has the methods `getKey()` to get the key value, and `getValue()` to get the value from the map (i.e. the object that you put in it).

It's good that you are planning to use it while iterating, as the documentation also warns that

> These Map.Entry objects are **valid only for the duration of the iteration**; more formally, the behavior of a map entry is undefined if the backing map has been modified after the entry was returned by the iterator

Choosing whether to use `keySet()` or `entrySet()` depends on if you want to use just the keys, or the values as well. If you don't want to do anything with the values (the objects you put in the map), you should just use `keySet()`.